# Software for runnable algorithmic organigrams

Tags: resource-request, algorithms, computational-thinking

I teach an algorithmics course at a level equivalent to first year of college. I discovered [LARP](https://www.tice-education.fr/index.php/tous-les-articles-er-ressources/articles-informatiques/582-larp-logiciel-dalgorithmes-et-de-resolution-de-problemes) (sorry it's in french), a software that allows to draw organigrams, run them, debug them step by step and even generate pseudo-code from the organigram.

It is great as a first introduction to thinking logically without the burden of the syntax. Yet it's runnable, so they can easily catch mistakes.

Unfortunately it looks like it hasn't been maintained for a while. It doesn't run on Linux (with wine) and isn't open source, therefore I can't update it myself.

I am looking for an alternative that would allow the same basic features, but that would run on windows, Linux and mac. Bonus point if it's a free software.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a visual-oriented tool anything like LARP, which looks very interesting. If you're unable to find a replacement for that, perhaps you could move up one level of abstraction and work with something which appears to use a pseudo-code input, with most of the supporting code automated. Multi-OS, free, OSS, GPL license. Oh, yea, it's also in French and aimed at French educational standards.
https://www.xm1math.net/algobox/

Answer (score 2):

[PseInt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pseint/) may help, it is placed in Sourceforge.net
Check some screenshots
[image: code and flowchart]

[image: flowchart classic]

[image: flowchart nassi-shneiderman]